# Does your level serve any purpose outside of PvE?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 2 you can play PvE, WvW, and PvP. When you play WvW and PvP you are at level 80, not your actual level. So is your level meaningless outside of PvE, or is there some reason for me to level my character even if I only intend to play in PvP and WvW?

Comment: Well with each level you do become more powerfull even in pvp, for example if you are lvl 10, that means you don't have traits yet. Your weapon damages are lower, even if you get lvl 80 in WvW. Your damage will be lower then when you are for example lvl 20 and get leveled to 80. Not to mention elite skills unlock at level 30... if you do WvW at lvl 10 your elite skill doesn't get unlocked.

Comment: @Lyrion AFAIK You get traits when you get leveled to 80 in PvP. But the slot skills do not get unlocked and the slot skills slots neither.

Comment: @PatrickStalder What??

Comment: @spauny You unlock slots for utility abilities by level. If you don't have them unlocked when joining PvP (getting set to level 80) you will have a disadvantage against level 80 player that have them unlocked.

Comment: @spauny Wipqozn's answer seems more precise. Just go with that. Turtles seem to always be right.

Comment: Just a comment on the question itself, since I'm not a Guild Wars 2 players, you're get downvotes likely because your question seems extremely vague (which you admit as much yourself). If you could do a bit more research and ask something more specific (eg. What benefits do I gain in WvW games if I level up in PvE areas?) you might see more positive feedback and more useful answers

Comment: I voted to close as "not constructive" because the question is useless. "What is the point of PvE?" well, the point is to play PvE. The question in it's current form can't be answered in an objective manner, so it's not fit for the Q&A format.

Comment: Can't it be edited to something along the lines of "Is there a point to leveling for a PvP player?" (the essence of the question is fine, it's the phrasing and especially the title that are off)

Comment: @dbemerlin I think the question is more in the lines of "What is the point of leveling" and then if you are doing pvp. Just like Fadeway said

Comment: I've voted to re-open. There's nothing wrong this this question. There was a lot of fluff in the original version, but I've edited that out to make the question more concise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're just going to play PvP then your level doesn't matter, because you're boosted to level 80, and have all your skills and trait points unlocked. However, in WvW only your *stats* are boosted to level 80. You'll still need to unlock skills and trait points by leveling up, they won't automatically be unlocked when you're in WvW like they are in PvP.

Comment: An addition to this is that you will have weapons of much lower quality (damage, etc) when you're boosted to 80 rather than if you are a 'natural' 80.

Answer (score 2):

Some elements of Guild Wars scale you up to max level to let you enjoy them fully without having to spend the time to get to the maximum level. Others don't. For most PvE stuff, you'll have to level normally: You can neither do dungeons nor progress in your personal story without leveling, and crafting would only be possible by either dodging mobs in high-level zones as you gather the materials, buying them from other players or receiving them from guildmates.

Regarding the PvP aspect, arenas require no level: they place everyone at an even playing field, as a level 80 character with appropriate gear. This mimics the PvP-only character mechanic that was present in GW1, where you could make a max-level, max-gear character that could only partake in PvP. For WvW, your stats get boosted to those of a level 80 character, but your traits and potentially skills lag behind: Still, leveling in PvE is not needed, as WvW, unlike arena PvP, gives you experience points (arguably a lot more than normal PvE).

Comment: You're saying that "still leveling in PVE is not needed", so don't you thing this is a bit disappointing? Why would you go for exploring everything in PvE and gain as much experience as you can get when it doesn't count against other players... You can enjoy the campaign and that's it - go for www or pvp ... for me this is very disappointing

Comment: You're implying that PvP is the only reason to play the game, and that exploring just for the sake of having seen the entire world *isn't* enjoyable. Lots of people play MMOs, everyone likes different things more.

Comment: No reason to force PvPers to grind. That's all there is to it.